# how to create chuncks of data with recycle unused elements javascript

Tags: javascript

Tring to make layout like Instagram explore page
but no luck with the data

if i have array of 100 object
each object have type member of image or video.

and i want expand them in chunks of 4 images and 1 video
like Instagram explore layout.

i use javascript

```
function organizeContent(array) {
    const chunks = [];
    let chunk = [];

    array.forEach(item => {
        if (chunk.length === 4) {
            chunks.push(chunk);
            chunk = [];
        }

        chunk.push(item);

        if (chunk.length === 4 && chunk.filter(item => item.type === 'image').length === 4) {
            chunks.push(chunk);
            chunk = [];
        }
    });

    if (chunk.length > 0) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
    }

    return chunks;
}

// Example usage:
const contentArray = [
    { type: 'image' },
    { type: 'image' },
    { type: 'image' },
    { type: 'image' },
    { type: 'video' },
    { type: 'image' },
    { type: 'image' },
    { type: 'image' },
    { type: 'image' },
    { type: 'image' },
    { type: 'image' },
    { type: 'video' },
    // Add more objects as needed...
];

const organizedChunks = organizeContent(contentArray);
console.log(organizedChunks);
```

Comment: Looks like you have 4 images for every 1 video, so you'll have to skip and overflow 1 image for each of your arrays.

Comment: Split content into images array and videos array.  Take next 4 images and next 1 video to construct a chunk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  function createChunks(dd) {
    const chunks = [];
    const posts = dd.posts;
    const images = posts.filter((post) => post.mimetype.includes("image"));
    const videos = posts.filter((post) => post.mimetype.includes("video"));
    let v = 0;
    let i = 0;
    let chunk = [];
    // console.log(images.length, videos.length);
    images.forEach((element, x) => {
      // console.log(i);
      if (i < 4) {
        chunk.push(element);
        i++;
      }

      if (i == 4) {
        // console.log("chunkNow", i, v, chunk);
        chunk.push(videos[v]);
        v++;
        i = 0;
        chunks.push(chunk);
        chunk = [];
      }
    });
    return { chunks };
  }

  const chuncks = createChunks(data);
```